# Calling functions in .dir-locals in Emacs

Tags: directory-local-variables

I'm trying to activate flycheck-mode by default when opening any file in my project's directory. I'm a bit of an elisp newbie, my .dir-locals.el file looks like this:

```
((nil . (mode . flycheck-mode))
 ((cmake-ide-dir . "~/workspace/Samira3D"))
 ((cmake-ide-build-dir . "~/workspace/Samira3D/build/")))
```

And the error I'm getting is

```
Invalid function: (nil mode . flycheck-mode)
```

How would I go about solving this?

Comment: You don't call functions in `.dir-locals.el`. The file only contains a list that encodes how the variables are set. See the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html) for details. The reason that you are getting this error I think is that flycheck mistreats the file as a usual el file.

Comment: I'd try whether the `eval` keyword is supported like with file-local variables.

Comment: I tried:
((nil . (cmake-ide-build-dir . "~/workspace/Samira3D/build")))
and it still gives me  
"Invalid function: (nil cmake-ide-build-dir . "~/workspace/Samira3D/build")"
@xuhdev

Comment: @xuhdev, of course, you can call functions in .dir-locals.el

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. Your list nesting is wrong.
2. You need to use the `eval` pseudo-variable to evaluate expressions / call functions.
3. Using `mode` to set a minor mode is deprecated. That's now for major modes only, and minor modes are enabled via `eval`.

I think you wanted this:

```el
((nil . ((eval . (flycheck-mode 1))
         (cmake-ide-dir . "~/workspace/Samira3D")
         (cmake-ide-build-dir . "~/workspace/Samira3D/build/"))))
```

Also have a read of this:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Dotted Pair Notation` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Sometimes you'll see examples of .dir-locals.el files using fewer dots and parentheses, and the difference (or indeed equivalence) between the different ways of formatting them might be confusing, so that will *hopefully* clarify the matter.

Comment: Nowadays you have to update `safe-local-eval-forms` for `eval` to work if `enable-local-variables` is `:safe`.