# Use lsp-mode for some projects and ggtags for others

Tags: directory-local-variables, gtags, lsp-mode

Is there a way to configure Emacs to activate lsp-mode for some projects and ggtags for other projects? Maybe using .dir-locals.el?

I code C++ and the project I most often work on doesn't support lsp-mode (I'm unable to create a working compile_commands.json because of unusual project structure). In this project I use ggtags. But when I work on other C++-projects I would like to use lsp-mode instead. But all configurations I have seen all load lsp-mode or ggtags based on prog-mode (c++-mode etc) and not on specific project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you want to use `.dir-locals.el` and assuming the enable/disable commands you need are functions, its pseudo-variable `eval`. If you have `lsp-mode` globally enabled, add something like this to the `.dir-locals.el` file in the root of your "odd" project:

```lisp
;;; Directory Local Variables
;;; For more information see (info "(emacs) Directory Variables")

;;; disable lsp-mode and enable ggtags-mode
((nil . ((eval . (lsp-mode -1))
         (eval . (ggtags-mode 1)))
))
```

(Note, I don't use either mode, so be sure you use the correct functions to disable `lsp-mode` and enable `ggtags-mode`.)

@phils has a [good answer here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/21956/12713) on formatting the `.dir-locals.el` file.

Comment: You can use the command [`add-dir-local-variable`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html) to do this, but I never seem to get it right.